# How to find which period has the highest value of termination in statistics?

Tags: r, statistics

I have an employee dataset, the format is as following(T means "Terminate", A means "Active"):

```
ID    Name    StayYears  Status  Country
1     John    3.5        T       USA
2     Mary    2.1        A       USA
3     Ben     1.7        T       French
4     Kevin   3.2        T       India
5     Cindy   2.6        A       French
6     Jack    3.9        A       USA
7     Peter   1.3        A       India
8     Andy    2.7        T       French
9     David   0.8        A       India
10    Nick    1.1        A       USA
```

Which statistic R method should I use to know which period(e.g. 1.5~2.0 years) and country has the highest terminate rate?

I am a newbie for R and Statistic, hope somebody can give me guidance, many thanks!!

Comment: You can create a grouping variable for stayYears using `cut`, grouped by that variable, and Country, find the number of T in Status i.e. `library(dplyr);df1 %>% group_by(yearGrp = cut(StayYears, breaks = seq(0, max(StayYears)+0.5, 0.5)), Country) %>% summarise(n = sum(Status=="T"))`

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this helps

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
 group_by(yearGrp = cut(StayYears, breaks = seq(0, max(StayYears)+0.5, 0.5)), Country) %>% 
 summarise(n = mean(Status=="T")) %>% 
 ungroup() %>%
 filter(n == max(n))
```